# Bottom align not working in ConstraintLayout with different ImageView sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I want some different sized `ImageView`s in `ConstraintLayout` to have the same bottom line.

The smaller picture has the size: `100x140`:
[image]

The larger picture has the size: `206x316`:
[image]

With the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8E8392">


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jbean"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p1"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jellybig"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/p1"
            android:id="@+id/p2"
    />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jellybig"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/p2"
            android:id="@+id/p3"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However it looks weird, as follows:

[image]

Update:
According to [Tamir Abutbul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217094/1319619), I've updated the layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#8E8392">


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.99"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/jbean"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p1"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.99"
            android:src="@drawable/jellybig"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p2"
    />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.99"
            android:src="@drawable/jellybig"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p3"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which I think it couldn't work as expected.

[image]

Comment: problem is with your  <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jbean"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p1"/> when you specify constraint start and constraint end with width 0 it will align view to center use horizontalbias =0 -- for left alignement and 1 for right alignmet

Comment: @NehaRathore Hi, I was wondering how may I fix this? I would be glad if you could enlighten me.

Comment: what is the expected behaviour of your UI

Comment: @NehaRathore Thanks for your reply. I want the right side larger bottles sit in the bottom, as the left side smaller bottle does.

Comment: can you add a sample screenshot of expected behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey unable to add this xml as comment, this is the xml for above image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/small"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/big"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/p3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/big"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p2" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8E8392">


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jbean"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p1"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jellybig"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p2"
    />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jellybig"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/p2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/p3"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know if not working

Comment: It looks exactly like the code in the question, please explain what you did to make your answer more understandable.

Comment: i change app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" for every imageview

Comment: @HardikBambhania I'm afraid that changing it to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` may not help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work for images with the same height and look like this:

[image]

But Different phones got different screen size, your images have fixed size and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

In `ConstraintLayout` you can work with percent on your views like this:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6" //line 1
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"  //line 2 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

**So what I did -** I told my button to be equal to 60% of its parent in height (see line 1) 
and also I told my button to be equal to 50% of its parent Width(see line 2).

You can implement this logic into your imageView to show different image size and keep a responsive layout.

Comment: Hi, I've tested your code and updated my answer, it seems that it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[image: output]

do you want something like this??

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I'd want to go with.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with an imageview that was constrained to the parents bottom but still showed some kind of margin. The solution was to add android:adjustViewBounds="true"